# The definition of number tags inside oneof with nested messages

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have three .proto files:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package first;

message Message {
    string a1 = 1;
    bool b1 = 2;
}
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

package second;

message Message {
    string a2 = 1;
}
```

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "first.proto";
import "second.proto";

package my_oneof;

message Message {
    oneof test {
        first.Message first = 1;
        second.Message second = 2;
    }
}
```

From my understanding, this oneof is supposed to work, but when I try this:

```py
from google.protobuf.json_format import ParseDict

import first_pb2 as First
import my_oneof_pb2 as MyOneOf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    json = {"a1": "testtest123", "b1": True}
    m = ParseDict(json, First.Message())
    x = MyOneOf.Message()
    x.ParseFromString(m.SerializeToString())
    print(x)
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File (hidden), line 10, in <module>
    x.ParseFromString(m.SerializeToString())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

Now the weird thing is, when I modify the number tags in the oneof a little bit, it works. In this instance, if I start the first field from `2` it finishes running without error, like so:

```
message Message {
    oneof test {
        first.Message first = 2;
        second.Message second = 3;
    }
}
```

What's the definition of the tags inside a oneof? If it's a oneof, and the tags mean where the data is located in the bytes, shouldn't all fields be `=1` as only one of them anyways is the one in every occurrence? Why does it work with `=2` but not with `=1` like I mentioned? I use protobuf 3.17.3 both for the python library and the compiler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The tags don't mean anything to do with where the bytes are located. `oneof` items operate exactly the same as `optional` fields, but:

- the library ensures that only one of them (at most) can be assigned a value at once
- the generated code may have extra pieces to discover which is assigned
- the generated code *may* (but doesn't have to) optimize the internals to exploit the fact that only one is assigned

As such, a message with a oneof is a *wrapper layer* around the contents. You can't simply write one of the inner messages then read it as though it were the outer message (the one with the oneof) - you'd actually need to manually create an instance of the outer message, assigning the relevant oneof field, and write *that*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not the question but I will use your knowledge to my advantage anyways if you may - Do you know any way then to get a serialized protobuf object (bytes), whom schema I don’t know (can be either `first` or `second` in our case) but I know it’s one of some options, decide in run time to which schema to try to deserialized it with? (That’s what I thought `oneof` does)

Comment: @user3804691 the way `oneof` works is by *adding a wrapper layer* with a field header that tells it which field (by number) it is; that's *how* it works; so: no, there's not a magic way of knowing which it is *without* that; you can check what fields it contains, but that is hard are implementation (language, etc) specific